# How to read csv file containing arabic characters using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a csv file containing Arabic characters. I need to read the csv file and convert into PDF whcih should have the same arabic characters written. Please guide.

Comment: Welcome. Please read the faq before asking. What have you tried? What exactly is your problem? Is it Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Are Arabic not at part of UTf-8 ? Beacuse if it is you should be able to do this:

```
public void unicodeShow(String fileName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "utf-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String a=br.readLine();
}
```

How to make a PDF I am not certain

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ISO/IEC 8859-6 character set when reading and writing the file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to determine the codepage your CSV file is using. This is most likely Windows code page [1256](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)

The use the java "[InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)" class, specifying the code page on the constructor

Something like:-

```
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"CP1256"))

    int data = reader.read();
    while(data != -1){
        char theChar = (char) data;
        data = reader.read();
    }

    reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..But the problem is I am using BufferedReader to read the whole line and I need to pick the seperate token which ahs Arabic characters to pass the same to the DB. Can u please help me in changing the above code to have Buffered reader and passing encoding cp1256.

Comment: @user1498024 -- see Edit. Note i am only gessing its 1256.

Answer (score 0):

For parsing csv I'd suggest using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

For creating a PDF, look [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) or you can try [Apache fop](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/).

You need to make sure you are working with UTF-8 and you shouldn't have a problem with the arabic chars.